# Не получается распарсить HTML страницу с автоподгрузкой контента

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Стоит задача получить данные о первых ста товарах. Страница не статичная, что на ней выводится по двадцать товаров, а динамическая. При прокрутке страницы вниз появляются новые товары. Для того чтобы получить данные каждого товара и спарсить их, мне надо получить ссылки на страницы этих товаров. Ссылки лежат в тэге `<a` в атрибуте `href`. Вот скрин части страницы в инспекторе кода:
[image: Стрелками показаны ссылки, которые мне надо получить.]

Пробую таким образом:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Article> listArticles = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc = 
        Jsoup.connect("https://flashdeals.aliexpress.com/en.htm?").get();

        Elements links = doc.select("div[class=deals-item-inner]");

        for (Element link : links){
            Elements url_href = link.select("a[href");
            String url = url_href.attr("href");
            listArticles.add(new Article(url));
        }

        listArticles.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Ничего не получаю, потому что не могу получить доступ к содержимому в `<div class="deals-item-inner"`
  Пробовал получить сразу ссылки во всех тегах `<a` `Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");` и в этом случае получал список из 70ти с небольшим ссылок, но в них ни одной нужной.
Докопался до того, что эти дивы подгружаются `javaScript` и поэтому `Jsoup` их не видит. Потому что он только может считывать и разбирать `HTML` код со страницы. А выполнять на ней какие-то сценарии не может.
  Подскажите, как я могу добраться до этих ссылок, чтобы закинуть их в свой список ? И как получить ссылки на первые 100 товаров ? 
Я установил `jBrowserDriver`, ссылки получил, но только 12шт, которые загружаются при открытии страницы. Осталась вторая часть вопроса. Как получить первые 100 ссылок ?

Comment: Так если страница динамическая, то может отследить запросы которыми она подгружает данные и их парсить?

Comment: Вам программа нужна или один раз сделать?)

Comment: Геннадий П, может и так, не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Stranger in the Q, я пробую сам написать парсер

Comment: @YutiiS попробуйте отследить запросы, если не получился пишите на Selenium

Comment: danilshik, какие запросы надо отслеживать ? это запросы, которые делает `javaScript` в базу данных ? если так, то каким образом я могу их отслеживать ? я новичок в этом деле...

Comment: @YuriiS Ну, например через тот-же DevTools в Chrome